# How to extract a value from a piped output to a variable repeatedly while the output is still being written

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, pipe

I want to update the download status at every 5 second of file to my telegram bot. Also here I'm using bash.

```bsh
aria2c $url --summary-interval=5 2>&1 | tee output.log | grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))"
```

This thing derive me download percentage after each 5 seconds. I want to use this download percentage for my bot to update it regularly.
I tried these

```bsh
aria2c $url --summary-interval=5 2>&1 | tee output.log | grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))" | { read text; curl -s "https://api.legram.org/bot${tg_token}/editMessageText" --data "message_id=${msg_id}&text=DOWNLOADED-${text}&chat_id=${ch_id}&parse_mode=HTML&disable_web_page_preview=True"; }
```

Try 2

```bsh
aria2c $url --summary-interval=5 2>&1 | tee output.log | text=$(grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))") | curl -s "https://api.legram.org/bot${tg_token}/editMessageText" --data "message_id=${msg_id}&text=DOWNLOADED-${text}%&chat_id=${ch_id}&parse_mode=HTML&disable_web_page_preview=True"; }
```

But none works. Then for testing I tried this

`aria2c $url --summary-interval=5 2>&1 | tee output.log | grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))" | { read text; echo "$text"; }`
Now with this I just got one output at last(which might be the first download %), unlike what it should be.
Can anyone get me the working code.